# Find :command being called from keyboard shortcut in vim

Tags: vim, command, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to lookup the :command being called in vim when I press the keyboard shortcut?

Ie. pressing `u` will do the equivalent of calling `:undo` in the command line. Is there a way to determine `:undo` if I only know the command `u`?

Comment: I don't think that every keypress maps to a unique command in the first place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but the (excellent) help will usually give you a big clue. For example, directly after the entry for `:help u`, there's the documentation for `:undo`. Likewise, shortly after `:help J`, there's the `:join` command. That should usually suffice.

In case the key is *mapped*, `:verbose map {key}` will tell you what it's mapped to, and by which plugin.